# working in css style

Tags: css

how can we make one div in front on another div?

Comment: In front of (above), in front of (left of), or on top of? The better your question, the better the quality of answers you'll get.

Comment: Please, change the title of this question to something more on topic.

Answer (score 2):

**[You can do that with CSS absolute positioning and z-index.](http://css-tricks.com/absolute-positioning-inside-relative-positioning/)**

**[See Demo Here](http://jsbin.com/oyuve4)**

```
<style type="text/css">
div { border:1px solid black; }
.infront {
background-color:#ff9900;
width:100px;
height: 100px;
position: relative;
top: 10;
left:80;
z-index: 2;
}
.behind {
background-color:#eeeeee;
width:100px;
height: 100px;
position: relative;
top: -60;
left:35;
z-index: 1;
}
</style>
<div class="infront">
In front
</div>
<div class="behind">
Behind
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the [z-index property](http://www.w3schools.com/Css/pr_pos_z-index.asp)

```
img
{
position:absolute;
left:0px;
top:0px;
z-index:-1;
}
```

or

Use the [position property](http://www.w3schools.com/Css/pr_class_position.asp)

```
h2
{
position:absolute;
left:100px;
top:150px;
}
```

Comment: oh wow, that was quite a lot of posts at the same time, all pretty much saying the same thing.

Answer (score 0):

Use absolute positioning in CSS:

```
#divbox {
 position: absolute;
 top: 0;
 right: 0;
}
```

There's also great article regarding positioning of elements in CSS:

http://www.barelyfitz.com/screencast/html-training/css/positioning/

Answer (score 0):

If you mean one div OVER another div, you probably need to look for the [z-index](http://w3schools.com/css/pr_pos_z-index.asp)

Answer (score 0):

Set the divs' [z-index](http://www.w3schools.com/Css/pr_pos_z-index.asp)

Answer (score 0):

You should make one div with `position:relative` or `position:absolute` and add a value of `z-index`, e.g.:

```
<!-- Assuming that this is the only content of the <body> element -->
<div style="position:absolute; z-index:10; top:10px; height:40px;"></div>
<div style="height:500px;"></div>
```

To distinguish, add a solid border to the DIVs.

Refer to:

- [CSS z-index property](http://www.w3schools.com/Css/pr_pos_z-index.asp)
- [CSS position property](http://www.w3schools.com/Css/pr_class_position.asp)